# Language Package not installing

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, language

I am getting a failed message when trying to download the dutch language package. I am going through the control panel > Clock,language and Region > Language. The windows update log is showing the following error:

```
*RESUMED* Download ClientId = Windows Language Pack Installer
Download call complete (succeeded = 0, succeeded with errors = 0, failed =   
1, unaccounted = 0)
Exit code = 0x00000000; Call error code = 0x80240022
* END *   Download ClientId = Windows Language Pack Installer
ISusInternal:: DisconnectCall failed, hr=8024000C
```

SYSTEM: windows 10 pro

### edit

CBS LOG (last 3 lines):

```
 Info                  CBS    WU creates the package, AppID:Windows Language 
 Control Panel, UpdateID:{C06F6F35-D92D-4094-81B1-B395F5338184}, revision: 
 202

Info                  CBS    Read out cached applicability from TiLight for 
package: Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-
Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~ko-KR~10.0.10586.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
   Info                  CBS    WU creates the package, AppID:Windows  
   Language Pack Installer, UpdateID:{E736662E-1BE3-4B91-9F36-6A91B804F9BD}, 
   revision: 200


 Info                  CBS    Read out cached applicability from TiLight for   
 package: Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-  
 Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~nl-NL~10.0.14276.1000, ApplicableState: 0, 
 CurrentState:0
```

Comment: Have you updated to Version 1511?

Comment: 0x80240022 = WU_E_ALL_UPDATES_FAILED = Operation failed for all the updates. I need the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to see more details.

Comment: sorry, the client's computer is off right now. But what should i be looking for in the CBS file? error that matches? or WU_E_ALL.....

Comment: forget it, share the complete folder as 1 large zip (copy the folder first to the desktop before trying to zip it) on your OneDrive and post a share link here.

Comment: have you uploaded the folder? For beginners looking at the logs can be confusing.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have any 3rd party security app or firewall, please disable them to see if your issue can be fixed.

Since this issue can be caused by incorrect wu server, check registry key below:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate

Remove the registry keys:

a.       WUServer
b.      WUStatusServer

Then, reset Windows update components to see if it can help to fix your issue:

How do I reset Windows Update components?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue.  My problem was that I was connected to the internet via wifi and for some reason my wifi connection was set as a metered connection.  Windows won't download language pack over a metered connection.  You can fix this by going to the connection properties:

[image: network connection properties]

and then turn metered connection off:

[image: metered connection]